# method of action class is not getting called in struts2

Tags: java, struts2

I am trying to call a method present in action class on click of submit button but method is not getting called.
here is my code---this is jsp page

```
<body>
<s:form method="POST" >
<a href="<s:url action="goback"/>">click here to go back</a>
<s:submit action="fileUploadAction" value="UploadFile"/>
<s:file name="fileUpload" label="Select a File to upload" size="40"/>
</s:form>
</body>
```

and this is struts.xml

```
<struts>
<package  name="default" extends="struts-default">
<action name="fileUploadAction" class="com.cdac.cloud.HelloWorld" method="uploadFile">
<result name="successfulupload">/success.jsp</result>
<result name="exception">/error.jsp</result> 
</action>
</package>
</struts>
```

earlier this submit button was in another page and it was working fine but when i moved it to another jsp page problems started

Comment: show you jsp code as well action class else its not possible to help you

Comment: i am showing jsp and struts.xml

Comment: what error you are getting and do you have `uploadFile`?

Comment: iam not getting error but on click of this button method "uploadFile" is not getting called and i have files to upload

Comment: can you show the action code (uploadFile method)

Comment: but code is working fine when button is in another jsp page

Comment: without the actual code its hard to say anything why its working on other jsp and not here

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<s:form action="fileUploadAction">
<a href="<s:url action="goback"/>">click here to go back</a>
<s:submit value="UploadFile"/>
<s:file name="fileUpload" label="Select a File to upload" size="40"/>
</s:form>
</body>
```

Comment: what error or exception you are facing or else what happening when you are clicking on submit. not working doesn't make sense to put in a right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out..!

```
 <body>                             
 <s:form name="something">                                          
 <a href="<s:url action="goback"/>">click here to go back</a>  
 <s:submit onclick="javascript:submit();"/>  
 <s:file name="fileUpload" label="Select a File to upload" size="40"/>  
 </s:form>  
 </body>
```

Then in JS,

```
function submit()  
{  
document.something.action="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/fileUploadAction";  
document.something.submit();  
}
```

I did not test this code..! post a comment if it is working..!